# SecurityManager.IsGranted() behaviour

Tags: c#, cas, securitymanager, principalpermission

can anybody please explain the following c# behaviour? I have written a small console application just to learn about CAS, but I can not seem to understand why the following lines of code work like they do:

```
string[] myRoles = new string[] { "role1", "role2", "role3" };
GenericIdentity myIdentity = new GenericIdentity("myUsername", "customAuthType");
GenericPrincipal myPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(myIdentity, myRoles);

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = myPrincipal;

Console.WriteLine(SecurityManager.IsGranted(new PrincipalPermission(null, "role1")));
Console.WriteLine(SecurityManager.IsGranted(new PrincipalPermission(null, "roleX")));
```

The output is "true" for both SecurityManager.IsGranted() calls.

If I then add the following lines:

```
 new PrincipalPermission(null, "role1").Demand();
 new PrincipalPermission(null, "roleX").Demand();
```

the first demand call passes, but the second one (as expected) causes a SecurityException.

Why does not the SecurityManager.IsGranted()-call return false for the "roleX" permission?

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4.0 SecurityManager.IsGranted has been made obsolete.

This is what it was and if you compile in .NET 4.0 compatibility it will complain.

```
bool isGranted = SecurityManager.IsGranted(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Infrastructure))
```

To fix it:

```
var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
permissionSet.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode));
bool isGranted = permissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet);
```

Reference:
http://www.stringbuilder.net/post/2009/07/31/In-NET-40-SecurityManagerIsGranted-is-obsolete.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From the answers to a similar question [here](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/261089-custom-permission-securitymanager-isgranted) it appears that IsGranted() only works with CAS permissions, and not non-CAS permissions.

Quotes from article:

> SecurityManager.IsGranted() determines
>   whether a permission is granted by
>   examining the CAS permissions that
>   have been granted by the
>   administrator. Since
>   WorkingTimePermission is a non-CAS
>   permission, that means the security
>   policies set by the administrator have
>   no impact regarding that permission.
>   In other words, there is no way for an
>   administrator to grant or revoke a
>   [non-CAS permission]. Therefore
>   SecurityManager.IsGranted() will
>   always return false for
>   [non-CAS permission].

and

> It took me a while to get used to CAS
>   vs. non-CAS permissions, and to
>   realize that key phrases like
>   "security policies" and "policy" only
>   apply to CAS permissions. Once I got
>   comfortable with that, deciphering
>   apparently innocent help entries like
>   SecurityManager.IsGranted's Remarks
>   section became much easier:
>
> "Granting of permissions is determined
>   by policy..."
>
> This implies - but doesn't explicitly
>   state - that the method only works
>   with CAS permissions, because it is
>   checking the current security policy.
>   It takes some getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `SecurityManager.IsGranted` is mainly looking at code demands (the assembly etc) - not specific demands such as principal permissions.

To do what you want:

```
    static bool HasAccess(string role)
    {
        IPrincipal principal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        return principal == null ? false : principal.IsInRole(role);
    }
```